# How do I update a label in a UITableViewCell (prototype cell) when the user taps the row in the table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create a simple list using a Table View (dynamic) with Table View Cells loaded with data from a simple array.

I am trying to update a label on the Table View Cell when the user taps a row in teh Table View.

ISSUE: for some reason I can update the lable on the selected cell but the cell turns GREY and I cannot DeSelect it using:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

but if I do NOT update the table view cell label, then the DeSelect works!

And vise-versa, if I remove the DeSelect row statement then the label update works!

I cannot get them to work at the same time :(

Here is my code I use to update the label:
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
 ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 cell.TitleLabel.text = @"testing";
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create a new cell with a dequeueReusableCellIdentifier in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, that's why your text isn't updating. This below code should solve your problems.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    ListCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];   
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.TitleLabel.text = @"testing";
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code solves the problem with the deselect but I have a custom cell and am trying to update the label "TitleLabel" in the example.  Your code writes over the entire row.  Is there a way to replace the code: [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text = @"New Text!" with something that refers to my custom cell?  (my list identifier is "ListCell" and the custom label is "TitleLabel"...  thank you so so much!!! :)

Comment: The ListCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; produces a compiler warning that ListCell and UITableViewCell are incompatible....  But it solved the problem and it works now!! :) (thanks)

Answer (score 0):

First, to get the selected cell use the cellForRowAtIndexPath  method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.TitleLabel.text = @"testing";

}
```

Second, to disable the selection style of your cell, set the  selectionStyle of your cell to  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone  in the  cellForRowAtIndexPath  method