# How to get controls from prototyped UITableViewCell when table row is selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with prototyped `UITableViewCell`. Inside each row I have a button (image) which I have to set as selected/not selected each time the row is selected. My prototyped cell uses custom class and design is made in Interface Builder. I try to use answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431152/how-do-i-update-a-label-in-a-uitableviewcell-prototype-cell-when-the-user-taps) question, but it is not working. It tells me that UITableViewCell have no such property and when I try to use my custom class it also gives me warning. How to fix this?

My code looks like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ///UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.self.btnCellSelect.selected = YES;

    [self updateValues];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: The answers below describing how to cast the cell to your custom class are correct, but you also need to store the selected state in your data model - you cannot rely on the value of the button in the cell, as cells will be reused when the tableview scrolls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast cell to your class, before accessing it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    YourCustomCellClass *cell = (YourCustomCellClass *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.self.btnCellSelect.selected = YES;
    [self updateValues];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: 10x, @l0gg3r. Stupid me to forget to make that cast.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is your cellForRowAtIndexPath is really returning an instance of your subclass, but the method signature says it returns the standard superclass UITableViewCell.

The answer is to cast this object to your class. The SAFE way to do this is by type checking the cell returned and then forcing the cast.

```
if ([cell isKindOfClass:[YourSubclass class]]) {
    YourSubclass *subclassCell = (YourSubclass *)cell;
    //Other stuff
}
```

Comment: Ok, @Acey, but I am sure that method returns that type of class, why make this check?

Comment: The only reason you are "sure" is because you didn't register any other cell types to your tableView and are only using this class as a data source for one tableView. It's mostly to prevent future programming errors, not so much runtime issues. It's a defensive programming practice and I would be remiss to not at least mention it in my answer =)

Comment: Aaaa, @Acey, I've got your point. True, it is proper one. I am in a hurry, and for that reason I did not think in such perspective.